# Figures hiding behind text below it

Tags: graphics, bounding-box, dvi-mode

I am preparing a paper for the SIAM journal and had lot of issues with including figures. Finally I converted my figures to pdf and added a `bb` field in `\includegraphics`. Now it produces output, but the figures are hiding behind the text which is following the figures. The `siamlatex1213.cls` file can be found at http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php.

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1in,bb=0 0 575 575]{wheelnode.pdf}
\label{Wheel node}
\end{center}
\caption{Wheel node Structure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am running this file by WinEdt. First I texify and then run `dvi to pdf`.
If I remove the `bb` field in `\includegraphics` it gives the error message: `wheelnode.bb not found`. I tried to include an image file here but failed as uploading of pdf files is not allowed.

Comment: You can't include `pdf` images in `dvi` mode.

Comment: If i use a .jpg file then it comes as a very small figure. maybe bounding box value is not correct. how to get proper display?

Comment: You can't use `jpg` images in `dvi` mode either! It sounds like you are using `pdf` mode, and that the bounding box is incorrect. You could try [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/), or make the `pdf` image available for download from another site and add a link here to get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: use a pdf converter that includes the correct bounding box. http://phaseportrait.blogspot.se/2007/06/bounding-boxes-and-eps-to-pdf.html seems to have decent advice.

Option 2: give the *correct* bounding box manually. The bounding box numbers are lower-right-x lower-right-y upper-left-x upper-left-y. In this case it seems the lower-left-y needs to be decreased (from 0). If you cannot read off the coordinates in some reader you will need to adjust manually, by trial-and-error. Decrease that second 0 and try again.